# How Can I export typescript interface which in namespace to use in another module?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, namespaces, typescript-typings

I have an interface like this:

`x.ts`:

```
 namespace Basex {
    export interface AddressDto  {
        AddressDetail?: string;
        AddressName?: string;
        AddressType?: number;
        City?: string;
        CityCode?: number;
        CountryCode?: number;
        DexjustizCode?: string;
        District?: string;
        HouseNumber?: number;
        HouseNumberDetail?: string;
        Id?: number;
        IsMainAddress?: boolean;
        LastAddressInterval?: string;
        Street?: string;
        Text?: string;
        Town?: string;
        ValidationLevel?: number;
        ValidityEndDate?: Date;
        ValidityStartDate?: Date;
     }  
}
    
// I use this object on my screen in this way;

const {Basex}  = require('../../src/model/dto/x');
```

I can access `AddressDto` like this `Basex.AddressDto`

But I could not achieve access to this namespace from another dependency project. I have tried using the above method to export in the dependency project's `index.ts`.But it could not be. Shortly How can access this namespace's interfaces from another dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the interface. please refer [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20273)

Comment: I think he export the interface already, but he has to export namespace too

Answer (score 0):

i think your answer is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#multi-file-namespaces).

maybe you can import it but in a weired way.
but first you should put that namespace in a separated file, then import it as the following:

```js
/// <reference path="PATH_TO_NAMESPACE.TS" />
```

i know it seems comment but you know that's ts :)

Comment: this is not directly related to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can also import your interface module on required location and from there you can pass it as a prop and I think this will be a convenient way

Ex: 
button.props.ts

```
import { ViewStyle, TextStyle, TouchableOpacityProps } from "react-native"
import { ButtonPresetNames } from "./button.presets"

export interface ButtonProps extends TouchableOpacityProps {
  /**
   * Text which is looked up via i18n.
   */
  tx?: string

  /**
   * The text to display if not using `tx` or nested components.
   */
  text?: string

  /**
   * An optional style override useful for padding & margin.
   */
  style?: ViewStyle | ViewStyle[]

  /**
   * An optional style override useful for the button text.
   */
  textStyle?: TextStyle | TextStyle[]

  /**
   * One of the different types of text presets.
   */
  preset?: ButtonPresetNames

  /**
   * One of the different types of text presets.
   */
  children?: React.ReactNode
}
```

inside button.tsx pass it as a prop

```
import * as React from "react"
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"
import { Text } from "../text"
import { viewPresets, textPresets } from "./button.presets"
import { ButtonProps } from "./button.props"
import { mergeAll, flatten } from "ramda"

/**
 * For your text displaying needs.
 *
 * This component is a HOC over the built-in React Native one.
 */
export function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
  // grab the props
  const { preset = "primary", tx, text, style: styleOverride, textStyle: textStyleOverride, children, ...rest } = props

  const viewStyle = mergeAll(flatten([viewPresets[preset] || viewPresets.primary, styleOverride]))
  const textStyle = mergeAll(flatten([textPresets[preset] || textPresets.primary, textStyleOverride]))

  const content = children || <Text tx={tx} text={text} style={textStyle} />

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={viewStyle} {...rest}>
      {content}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

And inside index.ts just simply export button.tsx

```
export * from "./button"
```